# SOLR Index can't find updated records

Tags: xml, solr, updates, solr4

(Newbie question)
I've inherited a SOLR4 installation and I'm learning as I go.

I need to update some documents by setting/adding the value of a field (field name="optout"). I'm using the Atomic document updates available in SOLR4. But, I'm doing something wrong. My documents are getting updated, but some fields now have multiple values. (Some documents already have a value for "optout").

But my real concern is that I can no longer find these records by searching for them. They seem to have dropped out of the index.

This is a typical document returned from search:

```
<doc><str name="id">myColl-myId</str>
    <str name="recordSystem_rid">622103814</str>
    <long name="_version_">1464135593682272256</long>
    <bool name="optout">false</bool>
</doc>
```

Some documents do not have the optout flag set.

My update URL looks like:

```
http://prodsolr01.cco:8983/solr/records/update?stream.body=<add><doc><field name="id">myColl-myId</field><field name="recordSystem_rid">622103814</field><field name="_version_">1462876089586024448</field><field name="optout" update="add">true</field></doc></add>&commit=true
```

After the update I can not find this record using the query used to get the record previously.

Do modified documents need to be re-indexed?

If I search by id, I can find the record, but it has been modified and now looks like this:

```
<doc>
<str name="id">myColl-myId</str>
<arr name="recordSystem_rid">
    <long>622103814</long>
    <long>622103814</long>
</arr>
<long name="_version_">1470576227169337344</long>
<bool name="optout">true</bool>
</doc>
```

Notice that there are two "recordSystem_rid" values.

Why are there two values for this field?

Any insights to this would be helpful.

UPDATE: Adding an exerpt from the schema.xml
Based on the schema available here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup

```
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
    <fields>
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="recordsystem_rid" type="long" index="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true" />
        <field name="_version_" type="long" index="true" stored="true" />
        ... dynamicFields are defined next....
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueId>
    <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
    ... copy fields are defined.....
    ... typed are defined ....
</schema>
```

Comment: Can you share your schema definition?

Comment: Based on the starter schema:

Comment: lot's of different sample schemas out there, in order to debug this would need to see the schema as it exists on your system today. If you can edit your question and add in the schema or add a link to a gist.

Comment: Sorry. friggin SO editing left out the schema I copy/pasted in my follow-up. Editing my original question.

Comment: After cut/pasting the excerpt from the schema.xml file I noticed that the "recordsystem_rid" field is defined with "multiValued=false" yet there appear to be multiple values stored in an array.

I'm wondering if the IT guys have a different version of the file on the production system (I am just a "developer" so I don't have access to the actual servers themselves!)

Comment: can you check your schema version? Should look something like this: <schema name="example" version="1.5">

Comment: It's 1.5 
    <schema name="example" version="1.5">

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies with your update url. With Solr Atomic updates if you want to change an existing field you are supposed to use "set". It's not clear to me what happens when you don't specify an action. Personally I'd avoid leaving it to default behavior in Solr when that behavior is undocumented.

So from your original update url:

```
http://prodsolr01.cco:8983/solr/records/update?stream.body=<add><doc><field name="id">myColl-myId</field><field name="recordSystem_rid">622103814</field><field name="_version_">1462876089586024448</field><field name="optout" update="add">true</field></doc></add>&commit=true
```

I'd change it to this:

```
http://prodsolr01.cco:8983/solr/records/update?stream.body=<add><doc><field name="id">myColl-myId</field><field name="recordSystem_rid" update="set">622103814</field><field name="_version_">1462876089586024448</field><field name="optout" update="add">true</field></doc></add>&commit=true
```

Note the addition of the `update="set"` to the recordSystem_rid field update.

I'd also be careful when mixing the Atomic update approach and the Optimistic Concurrency update approach using `_version_`. Definitely supported but I'd want to test it out carefully.

Comment: Follow up Newbie question:  Should I be omitting the _version_ field in my updates (off to google now). Not sure I understand that field.

Answer (score 0):

*version* is an internal field, updated automatically when doing an atomic update. You don't need to update it manually.

Nico